# Python - Store files in a network drive regularly using Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: python, windows, networking, scheduled-tasks, file-sharing

I have a python script which generates excel files and stores them in a network drive. The script runs fine when executed manually.
Since this work has to be done daily at a specific time, I tried using Windows Task Scheduler.

I am giving the complete UNC path of the network drive,

```
\\\\<server>\\path\\to\\directory\\
```

as was answered on other stackoverflow questions. However, the task scheduler works fine only when we select the "Run only when user is logged on" option.

How can we make the task scheduler run this script when the "run whether the user is logged on or not" option is selected ?

Comment: Are you saving the user's password to be able to access network shares that require the user's credentials?

Comment: @eryksun can u please explain how to do that

Comment: @eryksun Actually, I don't need any credentials to access network drive.

Comment: There's a "Do not store password" checkbox in the task's properties. Make sure that's not selected when you select the option "Run whether user is logged on or not".  When you click OK, you should be prompted with a dialog to enter the user's password. The password gets saved in the registry as an LSA secret, so the task scheduler can log the user on properly when it starts the task in the services session (session 0).

Comment: I did not check this "Do not store password" checkbox. But still, the task scheduler is not working with network drives when "Run whether user is logged on or not" is selected.